# What is the `except*` operator?

Tags: python, exception

I was sent this snippet of Python:

```py
try:
    raise ExceptionGroup('group', [ValueError(123)])
except* ValueError:
    print('Handling ValueError')
```

What does `except*` do?

Comment: This is something from PEP-654, slated for inclusion in Python 3.11.

Comment: It's a syntax error in all *current* versions of Python 3; 3.11 is not scheduled to be released until December at the earliest.

Answer (score 43):

`except*` is the new syntax for "Exception Groups" that will be added in Python 3.11.

See [PEP 654](https://peps.python.org/pep-0654/) (specifically [this](https://peps.python.org/pep-0654/#except) section) for more details.

In brief, it captures one or more `ValueError` exceptions that may be part of a raised `ExceptionGroup`, without preventing additional `except*` clauses from handling other exceptions in the same group.

Comment: Is this except* just syntactic sugar for a loop iteration over the exceptions in the group?

Comment: @AnishRamaswamy I suppose you could make that argument, but `except*` also handles things like recursive exception groups that would be a pain to un-nest by hand.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of the nested case thanks